# Tensorflow and GPU exhaustion during optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a policy network that plays Pong. When run, the GPU is exhausted after only three or four games, as if the data size is growing which it shouldn't be. The program plays and stores data quickly when the optimizer run line, sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict), is commented out. So I believe my handling of the optimizer and the amount of data is the problem? I am new to tensorflow and machine learning in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.  The following is a snippet of code (non-working) that gives the basic idea:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    legal_actions = [0,3,4]
    batch_dataSingle = np.zeros((1,210,160,3))

      while not gameOver:
        indexNum = 0 
        raw_RGB = []  #in format (210 X 160 x 3). This is saved so that the parameters can be reevaluated considering the entire point of play. It is reset after each point.
        reward = 0
          while reward == 0:    #Play game and store screenshots until point is scored
            raw_RGB.append(ale.getScreenRGB())
            batch_dataSingle[0,:,:,:] = raw_RGB[screenNum]
            screenNum = screenNum+1

            feed_dict = {train_data_node: batch_dataSingle}  
            proj_out = (sess.run(logits, feed_dict=feed_dict))
            indexMax =np.argmax(proj_out[0]) #Gives optimal action from weights

            for i in range(4)
              reward = result from running with projected action
              if reward != 0:
                break
          #We continue to choose a new action based on the current board until a reward is received
          batch_labels = reward
          n = len(raw_RGB)
          batch_data = np.zeros((n,210,160,3))
          for i in range(n):
            batch_data[i,:,:,:] =  raw_RGB[i]

          feed_dict = {train_data_node: batch_data, reward_node:batch_labels}  
          sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Optimizer algorithm:

```
logits = model(train_data_node, True)
loss = tf.log(tf.reduce_max(logits)) * reward_node * -1
batch = tf.Variable(0, dtype=data_type())
learning_rate = .1
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate,0.9).minimize(loss, global_step=batch)
```

Comment: Can you show the GPU logs?

Comment: Sure, thank you very much! I couldn't attach it above so the logs are located at this link. I hope this is what you wanted!    https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/taylor/out.txt